# Blender and video memory

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, render-layers

I have this question. My scene weighs 7 gigabytes of video memory (I have rtx 3060 ti), is it possible to reduce the size of the scene using layer rendering?

Comment: RTX 3060 ti has 8 GB VRAM (Right?). Your scene weighs 7 GB. Also if the different layers don't interact too much with each, or if a few losses are ok for you, then yes, using layers will help you with memory.

Comment: Thank you. I did the scene in layers. In the end memory is enough + fast rendering